# open jdk 11 sun.security.action no exist

Tags: openjdk-11

I am getting the below error when I try to compile my code:

**Error**

> can not found sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction

**Code**

```
 File tmpdir = new File(AccessController
                .doPrivileged(new GetPropertyAction("java.io.tmpdir")));
```

Comment: sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction is a JDK internal class so you shouldn't be using it directly.

Comment: en,i change to use Use java.security.PrivilegedAction